# Install outdoor power cable for Arlo Pro 2

Tags: wiring, security, stucco

Tired of going up and down to recharge battery for my arlo pro 2 in the front door, I am thinking to install a power cable for it, e.g., [this](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/outdoor-power-adapter-for-arlo-pro-pro-2-go-and-arlo-security-light-black/6234700.p?skuId=6234700&ref=212&loc=1&ref=212&loc=1&ds_rl=1268652&gclid=Cj0KCQjw-af6BRC5ARIsAALPIlUbG1l5XdZbBxk0NjK7v8tlYQgDPHoIM8rxs6A3HbpE15a3arPwMtMaApkZEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). However, not sure what is the best way, here are two thoughts in mind:

1. drill hole into wall (stucco) and route cable to attic, install a receptacle in attic to power it. (please see pic 1)
2. route cable to garage, drill hole into ceiling (wood) so I can connect cable to a outlet in garage. Drawback is that there's ~10 ft to the hole and I don't know how to clip the cable to stucco (please see pic 2).
3. probably the most code compliant, is to install an outdoor outlet somewhere but unfortunately there isn't any good nearby location to install one without routing a 25ft cable. Also there is sprinkler in front yard so any outdoor outlet nearby will suffer from heavy moisture even though it has cover.

Any suggestion how I should proceed?
[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]

Comment: Do you know what type of power connector that Arlo uses?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel just a regular QC 3.0 USB charger, but seems normal usb charger (eg iphone's) seems just work.

Answer (score 1):

If the space above the camera is readily available, I would go that route.  It would be worth the effort spent to purchase a 18 or 24" 2' drill bit from the Big box store to do the full length from your porch all the way to the ceiling.  Once the drill penetrate to the other side, attach a wire to the end of the bit and pull the wire.  Then attach the power cable to the wire and pull it through.  You can also add several layer of shrink insulation to the wire where it goes through the stucco.  I do this all the time.

Before drilling with the long bit, You can drill a 1/2 hole through the stucco, insert a short plastic liner in the hole to protect the wire against abrasion.  Once the power is attached to the camera, seal the hole back up. This is similar to installing a door bell.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like my option 1. I wonder what kind of seal I can use to seal the hole backup. I am thinking about foam insulator but not sure if there's better option.